# How to insert into a many_to_many table using Rails 3 active record from the console

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many set up and a read from the table but I can't seem to write to the table from rails console.

Household.first.appliances[0] = Appliance.first works while i'm in console and when I save it, it returns true but does not actually write to the database.

I'm using a remote mysql database and can write to all the other tables from the console just not the many_to_many. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Did you try to use the `save` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
household = Household.first
household.appliances << Appliance.first
household.save
```

Take care that you are not using the `--sandbox` option:

```
rails console
```

**not**

```
rails console --sandbox
```

Comment: Note the household.save is redundant, see section [4.3.4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference)

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a lot better to use `has_many` with the `:through` option than `has_and_belongs_to_many` because it's more flexible and avoids complications of this variety.

The primary difference between the two is that the `has_many` version has an `id` primary key column, so the records are addressable, and it is a first-class model so updating attributes on it is easy.

Here's a sample definition:

```
class Household < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :household_appliances
  has_many :appliances, :through => :household_appliances
end

class HouseholdAppliance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :household
  belongs_to :appliance
end

class Appliance < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :household_appliances
  has_many :households, :through => :household_appliances
end
```

Inserting into this structure is easy, and identical to the `has_and_belongs_to_many` way:

```
household = Household.first
household.appliances << appliance

household.appliances.count
# => 1
```

You do not need to save relationships like this, that is done automatically for you. Always inspect the output in `log/development.log` to ensure the `INSERT` statements represent the records that should be created.